# Android app fails to ping static ip of machine on same WLAN

Tags: android, rest

I have a RESTful service that runs on my tower and is connected to my home WiFi. I know the service works because I'm able to curl from a separate laptop on the WiFi and GET the correct data:

```
curl -g "http://192.168.1.2:8080/something/cool"
```

I've created an Android app that does the same GET. I made an AsyncTask that uses the Apache HTTP Client library that comes with Android API 19:

```
@Override
protected InputStream doInBackground(Void... params) {

    InputStream result = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.2:8080/something/cool");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);
        if (response != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            BufferedHttpEntity bufferedHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity());
            result = bufferedHttpEntity.getContent();
        } else {
            // insert error handling
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        reportError(e.getMessage());
    }

    return result;
}
```

The permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="anroid.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Installing the app on my Samsung S4 and connecting to my WiFi, I expected it to work. When the httpClient.execute(get) gets invoked, it kicks back:

```
Connection to http://192.168.1.2:8080 refused
```

At first I thought it was my app, but then I used the Pinger app to ping the same IP from my device and it failed. So now I'm beginning to think it's my phone, or at least the settings on my phone. Furthermore, when I pinged google.com, the app said my host IP was 173.XXX.XXX.XXX.

I tried messing around with the few WiFi settings available to me. I switch the IP setting from DHCP to static, and it didn't help.

Has anyone ran into this issue?

**UPDATE 1:**
Per the suggestion from a friend of mine, I turned the firewall on my server completely off, and I was able to ping using my phone. I then tried the to GET http://google.com and I got the same connection refused. I'm looking into why my request is wrong.

**UPDATE 2:**
I spelled android in "anroid.permission.INTERNET" incorrectly. My IDE was yelling at me about it too but I didn't notice. Tried to GET google.com, worked. Tried to GET 192.168.1.2:8080/something/cool, worked. Tried turning my firewall back on and then the GET, worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo in "anroid.permission.INTERNET". Fixed it and everything works as expected.